# JSON file not found upon uploading compiled Dart application

Tags: json, ftp, dart, http-status-code-404

I recently took an interest in [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), and followed their tutorial pirate badge. After completion, I built it and uploaded to my webserver. In the start of the app, it calls a .json file:

```
static Future readyThePirates() {
    var path = 'piratenames.json';
    return HttpRequest.getString(path).then(_parsePirateNamesFromJSON);
}

void main() {
    //... other code
    PirateName.readyThePirates()
        .then((_) {
            inputField.disabled = false;
            genButton.disabled = false;
            setBadgeName(getBadgeNameFromStorage());
         })
        .catchError((arrr){
            print('Error initializing pirate names: $arrr');
            badgeNameElement.text = 'Arrr! No names.';
         });
    }
    //... more code
}
```

Here is a screen of my FTP:

[image: ftp]

Obviously the file is there, but when I load it up in a browser I get an error. Inspecting in Chrome I get this:

[image: debug]

It works just fine when I run it in Dartium (from the Dart editor), not sure why it is having an issue on a live page.

Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: What is the actual URL for the JSON file on your server?

Comment: Could it be that your files are not in the recommended locations, and that `pub`, because of this, doesn't copy the necessary files into the build-directory? It looks like your files are in the top-level of the project instead of in a directory `bin` or `lib`.

Comment: Well, depending on what he's showing in the screenshot, we could be looking at `web/`, which should work. @Anders can you give more context?

Comment: I ran the compiler inside of the Dart IDE, and what you see on the FTP is exactly what it gave inside the publish folder, `pub` I believe.

Comment: All of these file are in the `/pirate/` directory on the server. It is the root folder of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using IIS?

I recently discovered [IIS would serve up 404s for any file extension it didn't know the mime type for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023492/iis7-default-mime-type-behavior); so my .sqlite files were showing 404s when I could see them on disk!

You can fix it in the IIS management interface, which basically just edits your web.config, inserting something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```